# White/Black screen appears instead of launch screen

Tags: objective-c

Launch screen displayed only in iPad. White/black screen appears when I run my app in iPhone.I have locked portrait orientation.how to set Launch screen for iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LaunchScreen with storyboard from iOS >= 7.1

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/

Comment: I'm using launch screen storyboard but it is loading whenever app comes to foreground

Comment: Do you try it on iPhone with iOS >= 7.1 ?